# Redraw panel contents after ClientSizeChanged

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So my application runs in fixed size window and in full screen. The problem I'm facing is how to properly scale the current contents of the panel (which depend on the application use) when the window is resized. This is my current code:

```
private void Form1_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix transformMatrix = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix();
    float px = panel2.Width;
    float py = panel2.Height;
    panel2.Width = this.Width / 2;
    panel2.Height = panel2.Width;
    panel2.Location = new Point(this.Width - panel2.Width - 30, 30);
    transformMatrix.Scale(panel2.Width / px, panel2.Height / py);
    panel2.Region.Transform(transformMatrix);
    //Rest of the code
}
```

But the drawn content doesn't scale, and if I use `Invalidate()` or `Refresh()` the drawn content gets cleared (the panel is redrawn empty). What am I missing?

Comment: Can you don't use `anchor` propety of the panel?

Comment: The anchor property only resizes and relocates `Control` objects, not the drawn content within the panel.

Comment: Did you mentioned that you have here the `Form1_ClientSizeChanged` event instead of the resize event of the panel? do you want to paint on the panel?

Comment: Yeah, basically I want to repaint everything that was present in the window before resizing properly scaled to a new size. But since the window used fixed size, the panel size changes only when the Form changes its size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET doesn't remember what's drawn on the panel, as simple as that. As soon as anything invalidates the windows bitmap buffer (causing a WM_PAINT), it's going to be repainted again. So, you have to draw what you want to draw using the `Paint` event (or overriding OnPaint).

However, there is another way that might be easier to implement - don't paint into a Panel. Instead, paint into a PictureBox (or rather, a Bitmap assigned to the Image property of the PictureBox). The Bitmap will be reused when invalidating (and redrawing) the picture box, so nothing will be lost. By using PictureBox.ScaleMode, you can define how you want the picture box to scale the bitmap, and it will do so as well as it can.

In any case, transforming the `Region` property doesn't do anything useful - you're simply changing the region, not doing anything to the drawing itself. To use 2D transformation matrices, you want to apply them on a `Graphics` object during the drawing (in `Paint` handler or `OnPaint` override) - drawing anything on the `Graphics` object will then transform everything you're trying to draw, which in your case means scaling the painting.

So you have to decide: do you want to just scale a stored bitmap with the painted image, or do you want to redraw it all from scratch (which also means you can pick any level of detail you can provide)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're mistaking what the `Region` property is meant for.  According to the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (empasis mine, replace 'window' with 'control' when reading):

*The window region is a collection of pixels within the window where the **operating system permits drawing**. The operating system does not display any portion of a window that lies outside of the window region. The coordinates of a control's region are relative to the upper-left corner of the control, not the client area of the control.*

All that you're doing is changing the region that the OS will allow painting, which explains why you're not seeing anything.  I think that you should be resizing the control when the form is resized, either through `Anchor`, or through my preference of `Dock` with several controls, or a *panel* like [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where it will handle scaling and relative sizing for you.

Comment: That's true. However, the panel resizes properly, but the content drawn within doesn't change.

Comment: What's the trigger for the client to resize (i.e. DPI change, application setting)?

Comment: Sorry for not answering, the trigger is **Maximize Form** event.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, but I wrote my own function and logic that serves the purpose for this application. Basically the function checks for the state of the application variables, and calls the appropriate function that originally drew the content, and since those functions use the panel width and height as arguments they properly scale the drawn content and retain the drawing composition.

P.S. I'll accept Luaan's answers since it offers a valid alternative and is complete.